# In Elasticsearch how to use multiple term filters when number of terms are not fixed they can vary?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I know for using multiple term filters one should use bools but the problem here is that i dont know how many terms there gonna be for example i want to filter results on strings with OR ("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") now i want my searches that will contain any of the strings but the problem is that sometimes this array size will be 15 or 10 or 20 now how can i handle number of terms in filters my code is given below.

```
var stores = docs.stores; // **THIS IS MY ARRAY OF STRINGS**
    client.search({
      index: 'merchants',
      type: shop_type,
      body: {
        query: {
          filtered: {
            filter: {
              bool: {
                must: [
                {
    //              term: { 'jeb_no': stores }, // HERE HOW TO FILTER ALL ARRAY STRINGS WITH OR CONDITION
                }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }, script_fields : {
          "area": {
            "script" : "doc['address.area2']+doc['address.area1']"
          }
        }       
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do. Use `terms` instead of `term`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "jeb_no": stores
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: oh man that damn worked like a charm thanks a lot for commenting a lot :) :)